# Rails 4 animate CSS fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, animation, jquery-animate

I'm using `animate.css` library for smooth css animation on my rails 4 app but i get an annoying bug only in production environment.

When i execute this javascript code:

```
$('#test').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
```

It works on my local machine and i get this problem only with fadeIn animation class.
Is it a problem with `css opacity`, `turbolinks`, or my `production environment`?
What i'm i doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, What's the annoying bug only in production environment?

Comment: The fact that only fadeIn css animation are not triggered

Comment: When i execute this code: 
$('#test').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
nothing happen...
But if i do:
$('#test').addClass('animated fadeOutRight');
It works for fadeOut animations.

Comment: You can now use [animate-rails](https://github.com/camelmasa/animate-rails) gem for `animate.css`

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have to add:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

into your **application.css** file.

What you also could do is: wait for the dom to load.

```
$(function() {
   $('#test').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
});
```

Have you precompiled your assets?
In Production you could do:

```
   $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And then run the server.
[source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

update:

It could be that it adds up all the class.
Let's try to remove them after.

```
$(function() {
var test = $('#test');
       test.removeClass();
       test.addClass('animated fadeInRight');
       test.removeClass();
       test.addClass('animated fadeOutRight');
       test.removeClass();
 });
```

Comment: I already have *= require_tree . in my application.css
I always precompile my assets.
It only fail when i trigger a fadeIn css class.
If i execute : $('#test').addClass('animated fadeOutRight');
It works... very strange

Comment: Wait it could be that it's a Jquery problem, I have edited code

Comment: then add "test.removeClass();" again after the last addClass(); edited code.

Comment: Nothing happen, only a small glitch

Comment: The strange thing is that it works on development environment!